# render html template with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have some flask code which renders a html document like this

```
html = render_template('test.html', data=data)
```

where test.html is given by

```
<div>
    {{ moment(data.date).fromNow() }}
</div>
```

I am using the moment.js file to print the time difference between now and the date. However, in the example above the moment function does not work. I tried to include the moment function into the template like

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
{% endblock %}
```

but this does not seem to do the trick... how can I get a javascript function to work in this context?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix JavaScript and Python

Comment: yes I am trying to render a template and feed the html code with javascript/ajax into the current view of the user

Comment: Can you post the full file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achive time since date and the date is anyway taken from python so why don't you use [timesince filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/33/). [Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#registering-filters) you will find about adding custom fitlers.
It would be more transparent solution i think.

Then it could look like this:

```
<div>
    {{ data.date|timesince }}
</div>
```